# Scanning Database for malicious Data

Tags: mysql, sql, hacked, verification

After a site of a friend has been hacked I told him he should just clean up the mess and restart from scratch so he know that no file has been altered.

I could scan the site for him with tools like grep an so on (For a start: [Grep and Friends](http://codex.wordpress.org/User%3aHakre/Grep_And_Friends)) but what I wondered about is, how to scan the database? What if some hacker has placed payload inside the database. Can be something simple like XSS or even PHP code in case there is some eval'ing still going on in core (or was at the time of the hack).

Any suggestions? I thought about using SQL-Queries with the LIKE comparison function or there is even some REGEX possible. But maybe someone has already done this or wants to do this an has some ideas to share.

Comment: I noticed, starting about 2 weeks ago, that the Google Analytic traffic for my WordPress site dropped dramatically. I finally realized that some hacker had gotten in and my blog was being forced to redirect to an assortment of spammy sites. Today I took a close look at the source code and found the page was calling up 2 javascripts that I didn't recognize. I went into my file manager and discovered that the dates on those 2 files had been changed about the day that my site was hacked. I ran my site thru the free site malware scan recommended above, http://sucuri.net/ and it also identified tho

Comment: @Pamela please do not use answers for discussion. You will be able to leave [comments](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) when you gain some reputation on site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've read that dumping the database as text and searching in it is a good way to go. You can search with phpmyadmin, but it's limited. Depends on the size of the database and a good text editor, but you can delete post/page revisions before dumping the database to bring it down in size. Or dump a few tables at a time.

Comment: Delete revisions prior scanning looks like a good strategy to me. I will ask the friend if he still needs them or not. You have any tips for actual search strings? But before asking, I think I should do my own homework and google things up for know vulnerabilities, I must have even linked some from my blog.

Comment: I'd look for the usual `eval(base64_decode` strings. And if you view source on the site and see spam links, search for those. http://sucuri.net/ keeps track of malware strings re: Wordpress

Answer (score 5):

My sites on one account all got infected with a Decode_Base64 script that infected many php files, and despite cleaning up a site which took hours, it got re-infected just hours later.

I ended up downloading the wp-content/uploads folder and any other manually updated files using a secure ftp connection.

I also took notes/backups of the themes, plugins, and other customizations which I would need to re-apply.

Then I changed all the account/ftp passwords, manually changed the database/user passwords using phpMyAdmin, to deny access when the sites came back up.

Next I deleted ALL the Wordpress code from ALL the sites and uploaded instead a simple index.html file that said the sites were under maintenance.

I checked the WP-content/uploads folders for anything that was not an image or my own content, especially looking for scripts (which should not be there).

Next, download the latest version of WP, configure it for the existing database with new password, and upload to the server.

Access the site, which will have only Akismet active at this time.  Check for and delete anything that should not be there (pages, posts, links etc).

Install a backup plugin to make sure you have backups of the database/folders.

Install the Bulletproof-Security plugin (or similar) which creates locked down .htaccess files for you and tells you how to secure your files/folders. Comply with it's recommendations.

Finally, gradually apply your customizations again.

If you have multiple domains, repeat as necessary.

In my situation, I was actually planning to move to a new host, so having done this, I then saved everything site by site and re-created them on the new host, once I was sure that the rebuilt old version was clean.

Good Luck and I hope this helps.